# How to close an app if I have an animation activity that calls another activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I created an app and the first page of the app is an animation that introduces my app. After 8 sec this activity calls the main activty; and it's working just fine. But when I close my app at the animation activity the main activity still gets called and the app opens again so how to fix that although I have added

`android:launchMode="singleTask"`

on my activities!!!

My code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {

                //Create an intent that will start the main activity.
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(AnimationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                AnimationActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

                //Finish splash activity so user can't go back to it.
                AnimationActivity.this.finish();

                //Apply splash exit (fade out) and main entry (fade in) animation transitions.
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein, R.anim.splashfadeout);
                //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
              }
            }, 8000);
```

Comment: for the ones who are downvoting; it's ok but can you tell me the cause is there anything wrong with my question maybe that way I can fix the problem It's my first app anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference your runnable and handler as a field, then when your activity close, just invoke handler.removeCallback(runnable) in the onDestroy method

Comment: thanks a lot it worked but just one question is there anything wrong with my question because I wanna know the reason of the downvotes.. so that I fix my questions next time.. thanks.